# Meteor autoform selectize select field not displaying all options

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm using Autoform with selectize and not all field options are displayed in template (1 of 10 it's working fine it seems).

I previously rendered forms manually without autoform and never had this issue.

This is my template helper:

```
properties: function() {

        var properties =[];

        var propertiesCursor = Properties.find();

        propertiesCursor.forEach(function(property) {
            properties.push({
                label: property.name,
                value: property._id
            });
        });

        return properties;

    }
```

And in my template:

```
{{> afFieldInput name='location.propertyId' type='selectize' options=properties}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, found it.. isReactiveOptions=true needs to be be set in template.

Selectize requirement, not in the docs.